# Need to change the background color or highlight entire row on click of a button in slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I have a slick grid and I need to highlight a row based on some conditions. I am new to slick grid and i am not getting how to achieve this.

When i click on save button, If there is any error particular row should highlight. Below is my save functionality.

```
$j("#save").click(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $j("#save").prop("disabled",true);
             $j.when(
              promiseUpsertOrderData()

            ).then(function(OrderResults) {
               if (OrderResults.errorList != null && OrderResults.errorList.length != 0 ) {
                   $errors = $j('#error');
                   $j($errors).empty();
                    $j('<ul>').appendTo($errors);
                    for (var i=0; i < OrderResults.errorList.length; i++)
                    {
                       $j("<li/>").html(OrderResults.errorList[i]).appendTo($errors);


                    }
                    $j('</ul>').appendTo($errors);
                    $errors.show();
                    $j("#save").prop("disabled",false);
                } else { 
                   $j('#error').html('').hide();
                   if (OrderResults.warningList != null && OrderResults.warningList.length != 0 ) {
                       $errors = $j('#error');
                       $j($errors).empty();
                        $j('<ul>').appendTo($errors);
                        for (var i=0; i < OrderResults.warningList.length; i++)
                        {
                           $j("<li/>").html(OrderResults.warningList[i]).appendTo($errors);


                        }
                        $j('</ul>').appendTo($errors);
                        $errors.show();
                        $j("#save").prop("disabled",false);
                    } 
                   initializeGrid(OrderResults);
                   $j.when(
                        $j('#success').html('Save Successful').show().fadeOut(10000)
                   ).done(
                        function(){
                            $j("#save").prop("disabled",false);         
                        }
                   );

                   grid.updateRowCount();
                   grid.render();
                }

             });
        });
```

Can any one please help me in achieving this.

Thanks in advance